# Victory js charts - Radar Chart & Polar Axis - How to set tick values like a clock

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-visualization, victory-charts

I want to create a data visualisation for daily weather temps And have it look like a clock with a central radar chart for the weather at each hour. I have my data from an API, and have made some progress in having it look somewhat correct, however... how do I set the ticks for the polar axis, on the outside so that 12 is at the top?

```
 <VictoryChart polar>
      <VictoryPolarAxis
        style={{
          axis: { stroke: "grey" },
        }}
        tickCount={12}
        labelPlacement={"vertical"}
      />
      <VictoryPolarAxis
        dependentAxis
        axisValue={hourly[0].time}
        tickCount={1}
        style={{
          axis: {
            stroke: "blue",
          },
        }}
      />
      <VictoryArea
        labelComponent={<VictoryLabel />}
        data={hourly}
        x="time"
        y="temp"
        interpolation={"basis"}
        style={{
          data: {
            fill: "none",
            stroke: "red",
            strokeWidth: "0.5",
          },
        }}
      />
      <VictoryLabel
        // text={`${hourly[0].temp} ${hourly[0].phrase}`}
        datum={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        backgroundStyle={{ fill: "pink" }}
        backgroundPadding={5}
      />
    </VictoryChar
```

[image: v1-data-vis-weather]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ive added in the code for my graph at present !